# Create a repeating glare effect over a coin in Flash

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, effects, mask

Please kindly advise the missing steps for adding a glare (shining) effect to a yellow circle symbol, representing a coin.

The effect should run every 2 seconds. The symbol will be exported and be `Embed`ed from inside of a Flex game.

I have already prepared the following and I think not much is missing, but I'm not a Flash expert.

I have created 3 layers called **Glare**, **Metal** and **Shadow**.

In the **Metal** layer I've created a yellow circle with darker outline by using the Oval tool.

In the **Glare** layer I've created 2 white rectangles without outline by using Rectangle tool and then skewed them a bit:

[image]

I think I need somehow to create a mask from the circle and then add a Tween to the **Glare** layer - so that the 2 white rectangles move to the right every 2 seconds, but are masked by yellow circle.

Please advise the steps for that in Flash CS5.5.

**UPDATE:** Thank you poepje, almost there... How to add the last frames? I've marked them with the red arrow below. There are several options there and I don't know if I should take *blank* or *key* frames?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the glare layer to the left of the coin on the first (key)frame
2. Make a new keyframe ahead in the timeline on that layer, for example at frame 15
3. Select this keyframe, select the glare object, and move it to the right of the coin (probably you'll want to put it at the same y position)
4. Make a copy of the layer containing the coin shape (make sure it's filled with a colour) and put that layer 2nd from the top (glare layer being the first one)
5. select the glare layer's frames from the first to the second keyframe (which probably would be all frames), right-click on the selected frames and select 'classic tween'.
6. If the tween is right, right-click the first layer and select 'mask'.

That should do it. As for the 2-second loop, just make enough frames (copied frames from one without a glare) to fill those 2 seconds; this depends on your framerate. With the standard framerate of 24, this would be 48 frames minus the ones that are already there (15 in my example).

Comment: Thank you, which kind of frames should the added frames be: blank or key? Please see my updated question

Comment: Blank just means it's empty. In your case it would probably be better to insert a non-blank keyframe, so that the glare image is already there on the stage. With a blank keyframe you would have to copy-paste it into that frame and reposition it, which would only be unneccesary extra work ;)